# Overflowing span inside TD with margin

Tags: html, css

I have a table show a issue / resolution status list.

Here's a sample row

[image]
As you can see, the resolution is indented using `margin-left` CSS and with width is set at 100% but it is overflowing into the next cell.

I've tried all variations of `display: inline / inline-block / inline-table` and also `float: left` and `overflow-x: hidden` but i cannot get the "silver bar" to stay inside the TD.

ETA: I'm not too clever with CSS :( but am trying :)

**Markup**

```
<div id="Log">
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            /* other cells removed */

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.LogEntry.Status)
                @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.LogEntry.ResetMessage))
                {
                    <br />
                    <span class="reset">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.LogEntry.ResetMessage)
                    </span>
                }
            </td>

            /* other cells removed */
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Log {
}

    #Log > table {
        color: white;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
        #Log > table tr th {
            background-color: darkblue;
        }

        #Log > table tr td {
            background-color: midnightblue;
        }

        #Log > table tr th,
        #Log > table tr td {
            border: thin solid white;
            vertical-align: top;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #Log > table tr td .reset {
            background-color: Silver;
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post jsfiddle/live link to check issue in action then it will be easy to help.

Comment: errrm... I'll try but never done that.

Comment: Then can you please provide live link to see as for fiddle  you will needed relevant html and css too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have set the `width` to `100%`, it will set the width of the child element to the width of the parent element. No matter if it has an indentation.

To fix this up, you can use the CSS function `calc`:

```
#Log > table tr td .reset {
    background-color: Silver;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px); // using the calc function to set width
                              // to 100% negative the 20px added on by
                              // the margin-left indentation
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can of course substitute `20px` with whatever you need.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Well... I never knew that ... thanks for that ... works a treat :)

Comment: @ChrisHammond no problem! happy to help :-)